# Wordpress get_permalink rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is there a way to re-generate the way permalinks work? I mean everywhere inside a blog ( all plugins & stuff which use `get_permalink()` ).

I want to replace all links like http://domain.com/wordpress/post_type/post to http://domain.com/post_type/post

The rewrite rules & stuff are done by htaccess, so if i access http://domain.com/post_type/post form address bar it works, so i just need to change the way how `get_permalink()` goes.

Note : I can not move the files outside the **/wordpress/** folder because in its root there is another html template.

Note2 : I tried some 301 redirects with regexp and i get **redirect loop**. So also if there is a way to change it with htaccess it would be great

Thanks a lot

Comment: May be this will help you...
`http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found. If you're checking the core you will see all filters https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/link-template.php. For custom post types it's `post_type_link` filter and for posts it's `post_link`. There are a lot of useful stuff, if you're going to read the code. The solution for my problem is :

```
define( 'SERVER_ROOT', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
define( 'INSTALL_URL', site_url() );

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'pleasure_post_links', 99 );
function pleasure_post_links( $permalink ) {
  return str_replace( INSTALL_URL , SERVER_ROOT, $permalink);
}
```

The code above will make the link `http://domain.com/wordpress_folder/custom_post_type` to `http://domain.com/custom_post_type`.

Also you might need this in your root .htaccess ( in the root folder, not wordpress folder )

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule   ^blog([^'"]+)?$  ./wordpress_folder/blog/$1
```

Where **blog** is the custom post type name and **wordpress_folder** is the instalation folder of wordpress

I hope it will be useful for somebody, i almost spend two days looking for a solution